# How to display multidimensional array in Angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I work on an application in Angular, and I would like to display data from a table like this:

[image]

Example of the array:

```
[
        {
            "Noms": "Boizard Clement ",
            "Enfants": null,
            "FP": true,
            "Adresse": null,
            "Brunch": "Oui",
            "OK": "Oui",
            "OK enfant": null,
            "KO": null,
            "Attente": null,
            "mail cadeau": null,
            "Remerciements": null,
            "Sexe": "Homme"
        },
        {
            "Noms": "Camille Giroud ",
            "Enfants": null,
            "FP": true,
            "Adresse": null,
            "Brunch": "Oui",
            "OK": "Oui",
            "OK enfant": null,
            "KO": null,
            "Attente": null,
            "mail cadeau": null,
            "Remerciements": null,
            "Sexe": "Femme"
        }
    ];
```

Is it possible? By using `ngFor` in another? If so how to make the array?

Comment: The code you sent is a flat array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code.

**home.html:-**

```
<h5 class="section-title h1">Table</h5>
<div class="row">
<!--  Table -->
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="image-flip">
        <div class="mainflip">
            <div class="frontside">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Noms : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Noms}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Enfants : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Enfants}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>FP : </span>
                                <span>{{item.FP}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Adresse : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Adresse}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Brunch : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Brunch}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>OK : </span>
                                <span>{{item.OK}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>OKenfant : </span>
                                <span>{{item.OKenfant}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>KO : </span>
                                <span>{{item.KO}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Attente : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Attente}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>mailcadeau : </span>
                                <span>{{item.mailcadeau}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Remerciements : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Remerciements}}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span>Sexe : </span>
                                <span>{{item.Sexe}}</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ./Table -->
</div>
```

**home.component.ts:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Array<any>;

  constructor(private _itemService: HomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.items = this._itemService.getItems();
  }

}
```

**home.module.ts:-**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeService } from './home-service';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    HomeComponent
],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
],
providers: [
    HomeService
],
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**home-service.ts:-**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";


@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

private items = new Array<any>(
    {
        Noms: "Boizard Clement ",
        Enfants: null,
        FP: true,
        Adresse: null,
        Brunch: "Oui",
        OK: "Oui",
        OKenfant: null,
        KO: null,
        Attente: null,
        mailcadeau: null,
        Remerciements: null,
        Sexe: "Homme"
    },
    {
        Noms: "Camille Giroud",
        Enfants: null,
        FP: true,
        Adresse: null,
        Brunch: "Oui",
        OK: "Oui",
        OKenfant: null,
        KO: null,
        Attente: null,
        mailcadeau: null,
        Remerciements: null,
        Sexe: "Femme"
    }
);

getItems(): Array<any> {
    return this.items;
}

getItem(id: number): any {
    return this.items.filter((item) => item.id === id)[0];
}
}
```